# Weblogic OSB - call function from another XQuery file

Tags: weblogic, xquery, osb

in Weblogic Service Bus 10g, I have an XQuery file with a function which I would like to utilize from within another XQuery file's function. How can I achieve this in OSB?

Projects/projectA/getMessageType XQuery:

```
declare namespace xf = "http://tempuri.org/projectA/getMessageType/";

declare function xf:getMessageType($anyType as element())
    as xs:string {

    ...
};

declare variable $anyType as element() external;

xf:getMessageType($anyType)
```

Projects/projectB/process XQuery:

```
declare namespace xf = "http://tempuri.org/projectB/process/";

declare function xf:process($data as element())
    as element() {

    // call projectA's getMessageType($data) here!!!
    ...
};
```

Thanks in advance,
PM

Answer (score 2):

You would need to play the `xf:getMessageType` function from `projectA` into a *library module* as opposed to a *main module*. You could then import the library module.

Consider something like:

Projects/projectA/getMessageType XQuery:

```
import module namespace common = "http://your.site.com/common";

declare namespace xf = "http://tempuri.org/projectA/getMessageType/";
declare variable $anyType as element() external;

common:getMessageType($anyType)
```

Projects/projectB/process XQuery:

```
import module namespace common = "http://your.site.com/common";

declare namespace xf = "http://tempuri.org/projectB/process/";

declare function xf:process($data as element())
    as element() {

    common:getMessageType(data)
    ...
};
```

Projects/common/common.xqy

```
module namespace common = "http://your.site.com/common";

declare function common:getMessageType($anyType as element())
    as xs:string {

    ...
};
```

You may need to add an `at` statement to the `import module` statement, specifying the file location of the common library module, but I am not sure what that would look like exactly in WebLogic OSB.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your answer. You are absolutely right in that putting the function into a library module would do the trick. I was just wondering whether it was possible to simply import another XQuery files' functions directly as this requirement was for a minor update in a system which is now in maintenance-mode only and in the process of being phased out (Therefore wanting to do without creating a module and updating every flow to make use of it instead).

Comment: Afraid not, the XQuery specification states that you can only import functions from a `library module`, not from a `main module`.